# MySQL How to use value of variable in a Query in its own Subquery

Tags: mysql, percentage

I am in need of your help:

I have a set of relational tables set up for Users, Games and Results and I am trying to calculate each users Win Percentage.

Thanks to a lot of browsing I have discovered the following method:

```
SELECT Winner, (COUNT(Winner) * games.TotalPlayed) AS PercentWon
FROM Results
JOIN (
  SELECT 100/COUNT(*) AS TotalPlayed
  FROM games
  where Player_1 = 'John' OR Player_2 = 'John'
) AS games

where Winner == 'John' 
GROUP BY Winner
ORDER BY PercentWon DESC;
```

This works perfectly for getting Johns %  but I want it to scan the whole Results table and print values for everyone. However, I am not allowed use:

```
SELECT Winner, (COUNT(Winner) * games.TotalPlayed) AS PercentWon
FROM Results
JOIN (
  SELECT 100/COUNT(*) AS TotalPlayed
  FROM games
  where Player_1 = Winner OR Player_2 = Winner
) AS games

where Winner != 'Draw' 
GROUP BY Winner
ORDER BY PercentWon DESC;
```

as Winner is not defined. How can I get the value of Winner passed to the subquery as it is being performed?

Comment: please post the structure (important columns of the results table)

Comment: Is there a player table?  If so, could you share its schema?

Comment: I will not be at my computer for a few hours, but I will when i get home. My primary goal is to get the value contained in "Winner" to be used in "where Player_1" . I would love to re-write my table but at this stage it is too far gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally come up with something that'll work for you.  It was tricky because the player can be in one of two fields in the `games` table.

```
SELECT player, (COALESCE(totalWon, 0) / count(*) * 100) as PercentWon
FROM ((SELECT DISTINCT Player_1 as player FROM games) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT Player_2 as player FROM games)) players
INNER JOIN games on (games.Player_1 = player or games.Player_2=player)
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT Winner, COUNT(Winner) as totalWon
    FROM Results
    WHERE Winner != 'Draw' 
    GROUP BY Winner
) as winners
ON winners.Winner = player
GROUP BY player
ORDER BY PercentWon DESC;
```

The UNION in the FROM clause is building a user list that I can use to join games (to find the total number of games per player) and winners (to find the number of wins per player).

COALESCE is used for the case when a player has not won any games.  Since we are joining table, this allows us to default 0 instead of NULL when there are no matches.

Here's an sqlfiddle based on my assumptions about your schema:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d762c/1/0

Comment: Thank you for your hasty reply but it did not work = Unknown column 'games.Player_1' in 'on clause'

Comment: Thanks again for the reply, it didn't work = Unknown column 'Results.Winner' in 'where clause'

Comment: That is truly amazing, it works perfectly. I never would have figured this technique out. I came up with a crazy method of taking the result of one query and using it as an array in another query. You did a great job, thank you for your time.